# Android Studio Build not working after migration from Eclipse

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I'm migrating my Android project from Eclipse to Android Studio. The original project relied on two apache libraries: commons-io-2.4.jar and commons-codec-1.9.jar.

I've copied these jar files to the proper libs directory and updated build.gradle  to reflect this:

```
dependencies {
compile project(':aviarySDK')
compile project(':showcaseView')
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/commons-cli-1.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/metadata-extractor-2.6.4.jar')
compile files('libs/tape-1.1.0.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar')
compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
```

}

When I try to build the project a I get a duplication error message:

```
    Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK /Users/gkipnis/repos/floomitandroidclient/floomItNewCamera/build/outputs/apk/floomItNewCamera-debug-unaligned.apk
Path in archive: META-INF/LICENSE.txt
Origin 1: /Users/gkipnis/repos/floomitandroidclient/floomItNewCamera/libs/commons-io-2.4.jar
Origin 2: /Users/gkipnis/repos/floomitandroidclient/floomItNewCamera/libs/commons-codec-1.9.jar
You can ignore those files in your build.gradle:
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
Error:Execution failed for task ':floomItNewCamera:packageDebug'.
> Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE.txt
    File 1: /Users/gkipnis/repos/floomitandroidclient/floomItNewCamera/libs/commons-io-2.4.jar
    File 2: /Users/gkipnis/repos/floomitandroidclient/floomItNewCamera/libs/commons-io-2.4.jar
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 3.144 secs
```

Can someone provide any pointers to what might be going on.

Thank You,
Gary Kipnis

Comment: The Gradle way to import external dependencies is to fetch them from a central repository, like so:
`compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"`, just like you already do with gson. You'll have to declare where it's fetched from, too: `repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}`. I'm not saying that this would solve your problem, just giving a hint for improvement.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by the error message add this part to your `build.gradle`

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this with the same result. But there is obviously some real setup problem since somehow two identical files are being referred to. What is this META-INF/LICENSE.txt file anyways and where is it located? I could not find it. Thanks.

Comment: Post your build.gradle (license.txt is inside the jar files)